# Datatable TypeError: f is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

Js Code:

```
$('#large-page-data').DataTable({
"processing":true,
"serverSide":true,
"ajax": 'getlargedataTables',
});
```

Data:

```
[{"Name":"Janet Andor","Term":"First Term","Date":"2016-09-26","Class":"J.H.S 1","Subject":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE","Exam":"CLASS WORK","Marks":"20"},{"Name":"Henry Kumi Kumson","Term":"First Term","Date":"2016-09-26","Class":"J.H.S 1","Subject":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE","Exam":"CLASS WORK","Marks":"24"},   
{"Name":"Jones Alonso","Term":"First Term","Date":"2016-09-26","Class":"J.H.S 1","Subject":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE","Exam":"CLASS WORK","Marks":"27"},{"Name":"Kingsley Offei Kumi","Term":"First Term","Date":"2016-09-26","Class":"J.H.S 1","Subject":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE","Exam":"CLASS WORK","Marks":"21"},
{"Name":"Mary Anderson","Term":"First Term","Date":"2016-09-26","Class":"J.H.S 1","Subject":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE","Exam":"CLASS WORK","Marks":"25"},{"Name":"Mary Boatemaa Duodu","Term":"First Term","Date":"2016-09-26","Class":"J.H.S 1","Subject":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE","Exam":"CLASS WORK","Marks":"22"}]
```

Table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="large-page-data">
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>NAME</th>
          <th>TERM</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>CLASS</th>
          <th>EXAM</th>
          <th>SUBJECT</th>
          <th>MARKS</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me to where i went wrong

Comment: what's the relation to php here?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Can you explain whole structure of your project?

Comment: *"Php Data"* - That isn't php, it's JSON data that probably was generated "by" PHP.

Comment: Its just what i used in encoding the data, but the problem is i am not able to process on datatable

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: I think your data is wrong format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data format is wrong. It should be like this:

```
{
data: [
    ["Janet Andor","First Term","2016-09-26","J.H.S 1","ENGLISH LANGUAGE","CLASS WORK","20"],
    ["Janet Andor","First Term","2016-09-26","J.H.S 1","ENGLISH LANGUAGE","CLASS WORK","20"],
    ["Janet Andor","First Term","2016-09-26","J.H.S 1","ENGLISH LANGUAGE","CLASS WORK","20"],
    ["Janet Andor","First Term","2016-09-26","J.H.S 1","ENGLISH LANGUAGE","CLASS WORK","20"]
]}
```

You can refer to this datatable example: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but it's one of the first ones to popup on a search.
For me the answer was to add **datasrc : ""** because I was using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages instead of MVC.

Example:

```
$('#BookList').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/api/Books/GetAllBooks",
                "method": "GET",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "visible": false },
                { "data": "name", "title": "Name" },

            ],
            "order": [[1, "asc"]]
        });
```